# Is there something that will need to configure with OBD2 or computer if I dissemble?

Tags: computer

The new cars has a lot of electronic devices and computers. As I like to maintain my family's cars I would like to know if I don't need to plug any OBD2 or computer after assemble or fix the cars.
I'm not a mechanic man, I just fix what I can. But sometimes I am afraid about dissemble and assemble something that later will need to plug a computer and configure something.

Comment: On most major brand automobiles, the minor things which it sounds like you'd be doing, there is nothing you'd have to do. The computer (or ECU/PCU) maintains it's factory settings. If you unplug the battery, the ECU will lose its "learned" memory, but it's nothing it won't relearn and nothing to reprogram. As long as you have the mechanical know how, you shouldn't have too much of an issue, but that's just my opinion. The only thing you need to look out for is to make sure you have the code for a radio if it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you do not need to adjust the computer after maintenance/repairs.

It might run rough for the first few trips while the computer re-adapts. Also, some cars will show a warning for things like "oil service due" if you do not tell the computer that this has happened.